# How do I recover data from a dead MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, ssd

Things I've tried:
All of the key combinations, it does not respond to any of them. I can't boot from anything external, I tried removing the SSD which is an OWC Mercury Aura Pro 6G. It doesn't respond to anything I do except reset the PRAM, and it just sits there forever, no fan, no apple logo or spinning wheel. Extra emphasis on the nothing. There may aswell be a uC connected to the LCD that outputs a blank grey screen because that's all it does.

I'm at a loss and I have no idea what to do. Going to the apple store is not an option, I can't afford the repair bill. This is a customers computer, they hired me to recover photos off of the SSD, and said I could keep the computer if I can fix it.

Comment: Gray screen is better than black, at least it tells you it is trying.

Comment: If you see a blank gray screen after starting up your computer, you may have a problem with a firmware update.

Comment: Apple doesn't perform data recovery. The bill would be $0 for that. Apple gives free, informed, options. The bill for that is also $0. It's not wrong to ask here, but why not get some input and ideas what to do from the maker of the equipment and their representatives before / after people chime in here with ideas.

Comment: Re "I can't boot from anything external" -- did you try the recovery drive (USB key) that the machine came with?

Comment: I was hired to recover the photos, I've already ordered an adapter to plug the SSD into my computer, that isn't the issue. Do I need to get a new logic board?

Comment: Another addition, holding option at boot does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There are reasons why good data recovery services are usually expensive. In your case you seem to have two options

- figure out why the Mac doesn't start anymore (with the SSD installed of course). There is a lot of material on http://support.apple.com/ describing various steps on how to recover an apparantly dead MacBook Air
- focus on data recovery by moving the SSD into an external enclosure, attach this to another Mac and access data from there.

Comment: Can you provide more specific link rather then to the main support screen.

Comment: I already purchased an external enclosure. I'll start reading that link, but nothing there has ever helped me in the past, so I'm not too hopeful.

Comment: Coming late to this party, but. I found that my best troubleshooting options come from the discussion boards. Search for "MacBook Air Boot problem" and if you don't find anything start in with likely synonyms or phrasing like "my Air won't boot" or "macbook boot issue."